# How to reverse a tag conversion?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

***A little background on 4D:*** The product was originally developed in 1984 and has been around for over 30 years. It consists of much more than just a simple database engine - it has its own [programming language](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-Language-Reference.100-2694908.en.html), complete with [plugins/modules](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D-Internet-Commands/15-R3/4D-Internet-Commands.100-2813441.en.html) for sending emails and writing custom TCP listeners or TCP clients using low level TCP comnmands, in addition to an integrated development environment for both [code](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Method-editor.300-2761336.en.html) and [user interface](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Form-editor.300-2761110.en.html), it uses a [structured query language](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-SQL-Reference.100-2809640.en.html) (sql-92 compliant), has a built in web server with features to help with building a SOAP server complete with an automatically updated WSDL file, it includes a [compiler](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Overview.300-2761357.en.html), and it allows you to [build double-clickable](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/Application-builder.300-2761316.en.html) applications for both Mac (.app) and Windows (.exe) consisting of either Singleuser or Client-Server deployments. It also has a [Plugin-SDK](http://sources.4d.com/trac/4d_4dpluginapi) for creating your own custom plugins making the possibilities with this software pretty limitless. There is more but I won't go on.

---

From looking at the [*tag history* of **4D**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10340313/revisions) it seems like this tag was originally created for, and specific to, the 4D programming environment.

It seems like someone suggested a tag-conversion of it in Jun of 2014 and although the suggestion was [rejected by some](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5158954), it was still approved.

This has led to the creation of the tag 4d-database and also 4th-dimension tags which are in essence duplicates of each other.

- [4th-dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4th-dimension) has 3 questions tagged, all also tagged with 4D-database
- [4d-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4d-database) has 54 questions tagged
- [4d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4d) has < 50 questions tagged, with multiple questions tagged ***both*** 4D and 4D-database.

**My question is:** Should this retag have been done in the first place; and is it possible to reverse the previous change?

I think that 4D-Math or 4D-Calculations makes more sense for the items that have to do with Math and Calculations, while 4D was a better suit for the programming language/environment known as 4D.

If we must disambiguate [4d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4d) then I think it would be appropriate that nothing be able to use that tag and we may need to also rename [2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d) and [3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3d) for completeness.

What do other people think is the appropriate tag for these items?

Comment: I think 4d-database is appropriate. 4th-dimension sounds more math or sci-fi related to me, even though the marketing blurb for 4D refers to 4th-dimension (or did at one time), so I think 4th-dimension should be removed. Although I understand the reference to 2D and 3D, it is a slightly different situation there, but it makes sense to be consistent.

Comment: [tag:4d], [tag:3d] and [tag:2d] are all meta tags. They are 90% of the time used in combination with graphics api or plotting and don't provide any useful information. Questions asking solely about one of the tags would be math problems and most probably not on-topic on SO. In combination with a graphics API they are rather useless because the graphics API implies that you are working with geometric data.

Answer (score 3):

Can we just merge these tags? Seems like 4D-database is the least ambiguous, but it really doesn't matter since essentially no one is misusing this; just pick a name. Given the breadth, perhaps "4d-platform" would be preferable?