# What should we do with [2d] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/2d/info) for [2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d)  describes the tag as a computer graphics tag. One may, however, see, that an insane percentage of question tagged [2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d) is not about computer graphics, but rather about 2D arrays or 2D lists, sometimes related to 2D geometry (graphics/physics), but very often not.

Random example from the newest:

- [How to use structs with 2D Arrays and Dynamic Memory Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785347/how-to-use-structs-with-2d-arrays-and-dynamic-memory-allocation)
- [Sort 2D list based on second column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710049/sort-2d-list-based-on-second-column)
- [Syntax of a function call that accepts a 2D list in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654916/syntax-of-a-function-call-that-accepts-a-2d-list-in-c-sharp)
- [Issues manipulating a 2d Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538213/issues-manipulating-a-2d-array)
- [Fill an array of strings until a sentinel value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519026/fill-an-array-of-strings-until-a-sentinel-value-is-found)

Should we do something about it? The [2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d) tag is currently used by over 4K questions.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274888/version-specific-synonyms-2d-array-3d-array-multidimensional-array

Comment: @rene: Yes, I've been there. But it hardly tackles the issue presented here, it deals with a different problem.

Comment: I know, I didn't check if the synonyms are already inplace but  one of the action could be to retag question to [tag:2d-array] and maybe the question can be extended to include more guidance how the clean-up should be done

Comment: Of course, retagging the respective questions to [tag:2d-array] is a part of the dealing with this issue. The synonyms mentioned in the linked question seem to work now.

Comment: @Dundee [tag:2d-graphics] would help to disambiguate also.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ True. But then we should have [2d-physics] as well, I guess. Or should we have a common [2d-geometry]? I don't feel competent (and I am surely not :) ) to resolve this.

Comment: We could flatten the tag...

Comment: Burn them all! To the stake!

Comment: [2d] or not [2d]?

Comment: i asked a sort of similar question about [tag:4d] here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317737/how-to-reverse-a-tag-conversion

Comment: If a question is using a tag incorrectly, shouldn't that be commented on within the individual posts that violate it?

Comment: Flatten the [2d] tag!

Comment: I think we should draw the line with that Flattened [2d] tag there, the point you are making is very one dimensional @valepu.

Comment: There is currently a [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4501964/szabolcs-p%C3%A1ll) retagging badly tagged questions with [tag:multidimensional-arrays].  Hope he will see this discussion (@szabolcs-páll).

Answer (score 4):

Accelerate it !

OK seriously, burninate it and replace it by `2d-graphics`, `2d-geometry` and `2d-arrays` seems the most sensible way to avoid those misunderstandings.

Comment: `2d-geometry` is different than `2d-graphics` in my opinion. For example, brenseham is about graphism, not about geometry. Whether two lines intersect is about geometry not graphism. So both could live no ? I add it in my answer

Comment: If you want to accelerate it, you'll need some accelerant.